# VSCode conda activate base giving CommandNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have Anaconda and Visual Studio Code installed on my computer. My default terminal for VS Code is Git Bash. When I open a new terminal in VSCode, it immediately runs the following commands:

```sh
C:/Users/ethan/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
conda activate base
```

The second of these commands gives the following error:

```sh
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
```

I have tried running `conda init bash` and `conda init --all` both inside the VSCode terminal, and inside Git Bash. It handles that command fine, but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't know if the second line of the error applies to me, but even if it did, I don't know how to change the command being called because it is done automatically by VSCode. This error occurs every time I launch a terminal in VSCode (even if I don't have any python files present in my workspace), and it happens both when I launch VSCode from the launch button in Anaconda Navigator and when I launch VSCode by itself.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. For me, easily resolved by launching VSC from the conda window.

Specifically, open your cmd prompt (for me, Anaconda Prompt), activate the environment using 'conda activate [envname]'. Then just run the command 'code'. This will launch VS Code with the activated environment and associated variables. From there, the debug works as expected.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, I've fixed it by adding the `Python.CondaPath` in settings.
Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and select Terminal Configuration. Search for `python.conda`, and paste your conda path for example. `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`

This will fix your issue.

[image]

Comment: Best long term solution ont his page! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I still get the error "conda was not recognized as a cmdlet".

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me go to setting and search for 
**Terminal.Integrated.Shellargs.Windows** 
and choose your preferred shell
[image: choosing CMD]

**update**
Its moved to 
**Terminal.Integrated.DefaultProfile**
[image: choosing CMD in your OS profile]

Comment: This solution worked for me:
1) To go the settings use Ctrl + Shift + P 
2) Then write **@feature:terminal default Profile:Windows** 
3) change it to the Command Prompt

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using Powershell. Start the Powershell as Administrator and then type

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Say yes if it asks a confirmation. Now, VSCode debugger option can be used with Python.

Comment: This worked it for me in windows 11

Answer (score 2):

In VS code settings, search for "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows", then click "Edit in settings.json". For me, this opened "%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json".
I set `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": "-i -l"` and this fixed it for me. My file:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": "-i -l"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `conda activate` command would cause `CommandNotFoundError`, use `source activate` command instead. It works the same.

I had the same issue. I got the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I solved it by manully run

```
source activate base
```

and Ta-da~  DONE!

This trick is simple, while needed every time you open a new git-bash terminal in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error as you. I solved it with a tip from a Python course in Udacity

Open Git Bash command line (NOT within VSC terminal) and go to your home folder, e.g., `/c/Users/arman`. Then run the following two commands but replace `[YOUR_PATH]` with your Anaconda installation folder

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:[YOUR_PATH]:[YOUR_PATH]/Scripts"' >> .bashrc
echo 'alias python="winpty python.exe"' >> .bashrc
```

For example in my case, as I have miniconda, I executed:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/arman/Miniconda3:/c/Users/arman/Miniconda3/Scripts"' >> .bashrc
echo 'alias python="winpty python.exe"' >> .bashrc
```

After this executing those lines, i.e., creating the .bashrc file, then run:

```
source .bashrc
```

Afterwards, open VSC and try running or debugging a python program. It worked for me!

Comment: thanks for this, did not work for me. conda still telling me "CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'."

Answer (score 1):

When I changed my default terminal in VS Code to cmd.exe I got conda to work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. In the end I changed my default VScode terminal to cmd instead of Powershell in the terminal default settings which was None for Windows. I had already added conda.exe to my path and changed the permissions as described above.
For some reason the activate.bat file was now found in the path which activated my virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is dedicated to Windows 10/11 users, based on PowerShell VS Code integrated terminal, and assumes using `miniconda` but the same holds for `conda` under the previous environment.

From the start menu type or search for **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** then right-click to open its file location. You should see the PowerShell shortcut. Right-click and open properties. In the target bar try to find `C:\Users\username\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ;` PowerShell script (.ps1). Using file explorer locate `C:\Users\username\miniconda3\shell\condabin`. Copy the content of that script.

In the default Documents folder create a folder named `WindowsPowerShell` if not exists and edit or create a new `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` script in it. Lastly, paste *by appending* the content of the former script.

You could do the same for the external PowerShell but the script under the path `C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` should be named `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

In other words, [the PowerShell profile script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2) enables the creation of aliases and defining functions that load every time you launch the shell. However, the changes take effect after restarting VS Code and/or PowerShell.